# Hotboot for Xperia L?

Tags: sony-xperia-l

Is there something like hotboot of HTC available for Xperia devices, is there some workaround for getting so?

Is there some custom software or kernel which I can flash and get a similar speed of boot?

Comment: `busybox kill` in terminal will do

Comment: Can you  be more specific about the command and write a detailed procedure?

Comment: It is a command you need terminal installed and you should be rooted and then `busybox kill` command will perform a faster reboot. Otherwise you can try apps like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.liveov.rebooter . Confirm me if it is working I will make it as an answer

Comment: I am rooted and I tried the commamd in terminal emulator. Nothing happened :(

Comment: Did u try the app which I mentioned. Did you type `su` and then `busybox kill`?

Comment: in Windows terminal or terminal emulator ?

Comment: terminal emulator

Comment: is it working now ?

Comment: No , it shows "kill : you need to specify whom to kill"